# Want to change multiple images by clicking image from a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, foreach

[image: when you click the "Edit Btn" then a pop-up box/modal will appear and it have images and we'll say this section "popup img". so when anyone click any of this images, user can select 4 images at a time from "popup img" section and click "save edit" in the popup/modal, then the "body img" will change with this 4 image that we click in the "popup img", no matter what how many time user want to save it, it'll work perfectly]

I use gsap.js for the pop-up/modal.  I use forEach so that it doesn't matter how many same section I'll add this site, it'll work fine. and my only goal is now, somehow perfectly work this. whenever you click the "button" for pop then i'll appear and then you got 9 images and select 4 image from them and click "save edit" and when you push "save edit" then the body image, there 4 images in the body, it'll change automatically. and you can change it again & again.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".mdlsc");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
items.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.querySelector(".opnBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    item.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "grid";
    gsap.to(item.querySelector(".modalwrap"), {
      scale: 1,
      ease: "elastic.out(1, 0.3)",
    });
  });
  item.querySelector(".ovlybg").addEventListener("click", () => {
    gsap.to(item.querySelector(".modalwrap"), {
      scale: 0,
      ease: "elastic.out(1, 0.3)",
    });
    item.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/wefdf.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
}
body img {
  width: 100%;
}
body button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  display: none;
}
.modal .ovlybg {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.modal .modalwrap {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 77px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #400df0, #6203b3, #940599);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 45px 0px;
}

.edtchp {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0px 2px;
}
.edtchp span {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}
.edtchp h1 {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

.clsebtn img {
  width: 120px;
}

.mdlsc {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.grypnk {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 18px 5px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.grypnk img {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.coinsc {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.coinsc .imdwidth {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.coinsc .imdwidth img {
  width: 45px;
}

.coin {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="main">
      <div class="coinsc">
        <div class="coin">
          <img
            src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-100.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-500.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-1000.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-3000.png"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>

        <div class="mdlsc">
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modalwrap antclr">
              <div class="edtchp">
                <h1>Edit Chip Rack</h1>
                <span>SELECT 4 CHIPS TO DISPLAY</span>
              </div>
              <div class="grypnk">
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-1.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-50.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-1000.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-5.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-100.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-3000.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-10.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-500.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-5000.png"
                  alt=""
                />
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="clsebtn" >
                <img
                  src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/saveedit.png"
                  alt=""
                />
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="ovlybg"></div>
          </div>
          <button class="opnBtn">
            <div class="imdwidth">
              <img
                src="https://polite-figolla-02d41d.netlify.app/img/Chips/chip-editchip.png"
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach. GsapJS library was not an obstacle when working on this solution. You will see that I have published the images separately, since your images were unpublished automatically.

Unless you save it, your changes will not be displayed. The number of chips to be selected here by the user is 4. It gives you an alert whenever you try to select more or save edit without at least 4 selected. So, you will have to deselect a gray one before selecting a new chip. I have used the term chip instead of coin here.

The implement I have used for the chips to look like flipping once clicked is the CSS animation. These materials/sources helped me when working on this,

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)
[bobbyhadz](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-add-class-to-clicked-element)

```js
//All items declared in a single object
const allChips = [{
      name: 'chip-val-1',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jFH4.image.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0wuFC.S0jFH4-image.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'chip-val-50',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0j11C.image.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0wlk4.S0j11C-image.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'chip-val-1000',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0j2wq.image.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0wORp.S0j2wq-image.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'chip-val-5',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jSZp.image.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0wd3f.S0jSZp-image.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'chip-val-100',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jqXP.image.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0wSU1.S0jqXP-image.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'chip-val-3000',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0j7Gm.chip-3000.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0wFjq.S0j7Gm-chip-3000.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'chip-val-10',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jI7r.chip-10.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0wXtD.S0jI7r-chip-10.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'chip-val-500',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jLAW.chip-500.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0w2TP.S0jLAW-chip-500.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'chip-val-5000',
      img: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jUp0.chip-5000.png',
      bk: 'https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0wq4m.S0jUp0-chip-5000.png'
   }
]

//Dedicated array for selected chips
let selectedChips = ['chip-val-100', "chip-val-500", "chip-val-1000", "chip-val-3000"];

const items = document.querySelectorAll(".mdlsc");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
items.forEach((item, index) => {
   item.querySelector(".opnBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      item.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "grid";
      gsap.to(item.querySelector(".modalwrap"), {
         scale: 1,
         ease: "elastic.out(1, 0.3)",
      });

      try {
         popupBoard();
      } catch (e) {
         console.error(e);
      }

   });
   item.querySelector(".ovlybg").addEventListener("click", () => {

      refreshSelectedChips();

      gsap.to(item.querySelector(".modalwrap"), {
         scale: 0,
         ease: "elastic.out(1, 0.3)",
      });
      item.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";

   });
   item.querySelector(".clsebtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      refreshSelectedChips('save');
      item.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";
   })
});

//Function for displaying selected chips
const refreshSelectedChips = (b) => {

   document.getElementById("selected-chips").innerHTML = '';
   const dyChips = document.querySelectorAll('.fliped');

   if (b === 'save') {
      if (dyChips.length !== 4) {
         alert("Please select 4 chips.")
         item.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "grid";
      } else {
         selectedChips = [];
         for (let i = 0; i < dyChips.length; i++) {
            selectedChips.push(dyChips[i].id);
         }
      }
   }


   document.getElementById("popup-board").innerHTML = '';
   populateBoard();

}

//Function for edit panel
const popupBoard = () => {

   for (let i = 0; i < allChips.length; i++) {

      let chipID = allChips[i].name;
      let chipFrontID = 'chip-front-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) + '-' + i;
      let chipBackID = 'chip-front-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) + '-' + i;

      const flipedStatus = (x) => {
         for (let y = 0; y < selectedChips.length; y++) {
            if (x === selectedChips[y]) {
               return `fliped`
            }
         }
      }

      //"popup-board" gets updated on save 
      document.getElementById("popup-board").innerHTML +=

         `<div class="chip"><div class="chip-inner ` + `${flipedStatus(allChips[i].name)}` + `" id=` + chipID + `>
            
            <div class="chip-front" id=` + chipFrontID + `>
            
            <img src=` + allChips[i].img + ` alt=` + allChips[i].name + `>
            
            </div><div class="chip-back" id=` + chipBackID + `>
            
            <img src=` + allChips[i].bk + ` alt=` + allChips[i].name + `>
            
            </div></div></div>`

      const dyChips = document.querySelectorAll('.chip-inner');

      for (let dy of dyChips) {
         dy.addEventListener('click', function flipClick() {

            if (dy.classList.contains('fliped')) {
               dy.classList.remove('fliped');
            } else {
               if (document.querySelectorAll('.fliped').length >= 4) {
                  alert("Only 4 chips can be selected.");
               } else {
                  dy.classList.add('fliped');
               }

            }
         })
      }
   }
}

//Displaying the selected items at startup
const populateBoard = () => {

   selectedChips.forEach(name => {
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.alt = name;
      for (let i = 0; i < allChips.length; i++) {
         if (name === allChips[i].name) {
            img.src = allChips[i].img;
         }
      }
      window["selected-chips"].appendChild(img);
   })
}


//Initial trigger for displaying the selected items
try {
   populateBoard();
} catch (e) {
   console.error(e);
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jypz.download.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100vh;
}

body img {
    width: 100%;
}

body button {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.main {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    display: none;
}

.modal .ovlybg {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal .modalwrap {
    transform: scale(0);
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    height: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 77px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #400df0, #6203b3, #940599);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 45px 0px;
}

.edtchp {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 0px 2px;
}

.edtchp span {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}

.edtchp h1 {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

.clsebtn img {
    width: 120px;
}

.mdlsc {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.grypnk {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 18px 5px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.grypnk img {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.coinsc {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    gap: 8px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.coinsc .imdwidth {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.coinsc .imdwidth img {
    width: 45px;
}

.coin {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 5px;
    align-items: center;
}


/*I have used the term chip instead of coin here*/
.chip:nth-child(n+4) {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.chip:nth-child(n+7) {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.chip {
    background-color: transparent;
    perspective: 1000px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*Animation when a chip is clicked/selected*/
.chip-inner {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.chip .chip-inner.fliped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.chip-front,
.chip-back {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    /*Backface is hidden since it reveals as chip flips*/
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.chip-back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="main">
         <div class="coinsc">
            <div class="coin" id="selected-chips">
            </div>
            <div class="mdlsc">
               <div class="modal">
                  <div class="modalwrap antclr">
                     <div class="edtchp">
                        <h1>Edit Chip Rack</h1>
                        <span>SELECT 4 CHIPS TO DISPLAY</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="grypnk" id="popup-board">
                     </div>
                     <a href="#" class="clsebtn">
                     <img
                        src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jmix.saveedit.png"
                        alt=""
                        />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ovlybg"></div>
               </div>
               <button class="opnBtn">
                  <div class="imdwidth">
                     <img
                        src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jwca.chip-editchip.png"
                        alt=""
                        />
                  </div>
               </button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```